# Lost my SQL Server 2005 host, SQL Server 2005 database import into SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

My SQL Server 2005 host died, but the database related LUNS were on a SAN and still exist.  Is there a way to use my SQL Server 2012 host to recover that database or import it in some way?

Comment: Have you worked through the steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: you can use `SLQ Server Manager Studio` to restore your database to a new location.

Here, msdn explain how to do it
   `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx`

Comment: Wll, you do have a backup, right? If not - what do you care about the data now?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute best way would be to [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx) onto 2012 from backups if you have them, but you can also [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187858.aspx) the databases from the SAN files onto your 2012 instance.

Once you do that, be sure to run [DBCC CHECKDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) to make sure all your data is intact.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem and is [extensively documented online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx) with [Management Studio specific steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx) as linked by angel

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that restoring a database from an older version (e.g. SQL Server 2005) to a newer one (e.g. SQL Server 2012), i.e. upgrading is usually smooth. The issues are encountered when restoring SQL Server 2000 and older databases to SQL Server 2012 and newer.

Downgrading - restoring a SQL Server 2012 database to a SQL Server 2005 instance is troublesome.